# Conditionally piping to Out-Null

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell script to `msbuild` a bunch of solutions. I want to count how many solutions build successfully and how many fail. I also want to see the compiler errors, but only from the first one that fails (I'm assuming the others will usually have similar errors and I don't want to clutter my output).

My question is about how to run an external command (`msbuild` in this case), but conditionally pipe its output. If I'm running it and haven't gotten any failures yet, I don't want to pipe its output; I want it to output directly to the console, with no redirection, so it will color-code its output. (Like many programs, msbuild turns off color-coding if it sees that its stdout is redirected.) But if I have gotten failures before, I want to pipe to `Out-Null`.

Obviously I could do this:

```
if ($SolutionsWithErrors -eq 0) {
    msbuild $Path /nologo /v:q /consoleloggerparameters:ErrorsOnly
} else {
    msbuild $Path /nologo /v:q /consoleloggerparameters:ErrorsOnly | Out-Null
}
```

But it seems like there's got to be a way to do it without the duplication. (Okay, it doesn't have to be duplication -- I could leave off `/consoleloggerparameters` if I'm piping to null anyway -- but you get the idea.)

There may be other ways to solve this, but for today, I specifically want to know: is there a way to run a command, but only pipe its output if a certain condition is met (and otherwise not pipe it or redirect its output at all, so it can do fancy stuff like color-coded output)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define the output command as a variable and use either `Out-Default` or `Out-Null`:

```
# set the output command depending on the condition
$output = if ($SolutionsWithErrors -eq 0) {'Out-Default'} else {'Out-Null'}

# invoke the command with the variable output
msbuild $Path /nologo /v:q /consoleloggerparameters:ErrorsOnly | & $output
```

---

UPDATE

The above code loses MSBuild colors. In order to preserve colors and yet avoid
duplication of code this approach can be used:

```
# define the command once as a script block
$command = {msbuild $Path /nologo /v:q /consoleloggerparameters:ErrorsOnly}

# invoke the command with output depending on the condition
if ($SolutionsWithErrors -eq 0) {& $command} else {& $command | Out-Null}
```

---

> is there a way to run a command, but only pipe its output if a certain condition is met (and otherwise not pipe it or redirect its output at all, so it can do fancy stuff like color-coded output)?

There is no such a way built-in, more likely. But it can be implemented with a function and the function is reused as such a way:

```
function Invoke-WithOutput($OutputCondition, $Command) {
    if ($OutputCondition) { & $Command } else { $null = & $Command }
}

Invoke-WithOutput ($SolutionsWithErrors -eq 0) {
    msbuild $Path /nologo /v:q /consoleloggerparameters:ErrorsOnly
}
```

Comment: That's a good thought, but unfortunately, that's still redirecting, so I lose msbuild's color-coded output.

Comment: True. I have added yet another approach to the answer. It is still not perfect but at least avoids duplication of code and keeps colors.