# Conditionally write output to file for tracing pourposes

Tags: powershell, pipe, conditional-statements, write-host

I have a script that accept "-outToFilename" as not mandatory parameter with the purpose,if wanted, to have a log on both console and file. Usually I'm using functions like this:

```powershell
function myLogger {
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$myMessage,       
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$logToFile
    )
    if ($logToFile) {
       write-host $myMessage |tee -append -filePath $logToFile
    } else {
       write-host $myMessage
}
```

But while playing with *Tee-Object* I was wondering whether it is possible to conditionally pipe the output of a *write-host*  cmdlet to a tee-object
Something like this:

```powershell
write-host $myMessage | if ($logToFile) { $_ | tee -filePath $logToFile }<br/>
```

**EDIT**
 with *tee-Object* is better to use **write-output** so that Tee can get values from the pipeline:
write-output $myMessage | if ($logToFile) { $_ | tee -filePath $logToFile }

also, while waiting for a better solution, when I need a conditionally output to (both) console and file, I'm using this:

```powershell
write-host -ForegroundColor yellow "Some text to show"
if ( $saveToFile) { Write-output  "Some text to show" | tee -FilePath $saveToFile -Append |Out-Null }
```

Comment: You would need to place the condition before the `Write-Host`. You cannot pipe something to an `if` statement. ;-)

Comment: from what i can tell, the `Write-Host` cmdlet does not output ANYTHING to the output stream - and thus nothing for a pipe to send onward. no `-PassThru`, no `-OutVariable`, no `-PipelineVariable` ... _nothing_. [*grin*]

Comment: BTW: You wouldn't actually need a `Write-Host` to output something to the console AND to a file with `Tee-Object`. Just *call* your variable `$myMessage` as it is and pipe that to `Tee-Object` ;-)

Comment: @Olaf yes, actually I'm doing this "if statement" thing **if {$file) {write-output $msg | tee -filepath $file} else {write-host $message}** but I don't like to duplicate code, specially when $message is a string that changes many time.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey  yep, You are right, I discovered that tight after posting the message. I'm using  **write-output**  for the **Tee-Object** and **write-host** for standard output

Comment: My previous searches pointed to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694007/conditionally-piping-to-out-null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694007/conditionally-piping-to-out-null)   but I'm not able to replace **out-Null** with **out-file -path $path**  or whatever command

Comment: @pink0.pallino - kool! glad to know that you found a fix ... [*grin*]

Comment: @pink0.pallino ... but your question shows another code snippet. You might update your question with the code you're actually using.  ;-)